# Connect devices to shared apartment Wi-Fi? (Apple TV, MacBook, and Wi-Fi printer)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

My wife and I are students staying in an apartment complex. The complex company provides a large Wi-Fi network for the whole complex. I would like to connect our devices on the network over Wi-Fi, but am having trouble doing so (I assume) because it is a large network with multiple routers. My Apple TV cannot find my computer in order to do home sharing, and my computer can’t find my Wi-Fi enabled printer. These problems exist despite all devices being connected to the same network, but (I presume) different routers. Is there any way to fix this? Is there any other interpretation of the issue that may point me in the right direction?

Comment: You've probably also got some security mechanism running in the background of the building preventing network devices from connecting to one another - I.e. Internet only and to prevent your neighbour hacking into your devices. You may have to look at taking to your building network provider to see if it is possible or ask them if you could use your own router to create your own flat LAN and use the Internet...

Answer (score 0):

Your devices cannot talk to each other because it is the campus wifi, not your personal wifi. As  Big Chris said, this is a security feature that keep others from accessing your devices as well. If you want personal wifi you will need to purchase your own internet service complete with a wireless router of your own. OR you could purchase something like a  TP-LINK TL-WR843ND which will connect to the apartment complex wifi and provide you personal wifi and even ethernet ports for your printer.